# How do you autosize a winform?

Tags: windows, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a form.. I want to bring it to 400 by 400 from 1000 by 1000.. when i drag it in the design mode..scroll bars appear and it content of the board doesnt shrink proportionally with my shrinking (by dragging the corner of the winform form inwards)..

How can i autosize the content of the form with my mouse drag?

Comment: No user interface works like that.  Shrinking controls and text 2.5 times smaller makes the UI unusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Dock and Anchor properties for your controls.  Winforms does not scale the way WPF does with its vectors-- it's pixel based.

Either that, or make sure your AutoScrollMinSize is equal to 0, 0

For example:

On a button, if I highlight the gray bars for my anchors, the button will stay move with the bottom-right corner of the form.

[image]

Comment: I have no anchor no dock properties in my form properties

Comment: @Dmitry Update answer.  The controls inside the form are where you need to look at for those properties.

Comment: None of that works. The dock properties of the controls ..really mess things up..The anchor properties dont appear to do anything and Autoscrollmin is already set to 0,0..it solves nothing

Comment: @Dmitry The anchors should be doing everything for you,  I uploaded an example.